# How to verify whether a point lies within a sector formed by the geocoordinates

Tags: java, google-maps, geometry

I have written a Java code that verifies whether a point lies within a sector of a circle defined radius. Both the point and the circle centre are represented in terms of latitude and longitude.

The Java code is as follows-

```
public boolean isPointWithin(float centreLat,float centreLong,float pointLat,float pointLong,int maxDistance)
    {                               
        float adjFactor=0.0f;
        double angleRange,bisectorIVector,bisectorJVector,IVector,JVector,VectorLength,dotProduct,EnodeBAngle,
        latScale=0.0,longScale=0.0,distance,lower,upper,count,adjustmentFactor=0.0,jVector,dist1,dist2;
        dist1=Math.pow(centreLat-pointLat, 2)+Math.pow(centreLong-pointLong, 2);
        dist2=Math.pow(centreLat-pointLat, 2)+Math.pow(360-(Math.abs(centreLong)+Math.abs(pointLong)), 2);
        if(dist1>dist2)
        {
            adjFactor=360-(Math.abs(pointLong)+Math.abs(centreLong));
            if(centreLong>0)
                pointLong=(centreLong+adjFactor);
            else
                pointLong=(centreLong-adjFactor);
        }
        latScale=(111132.954-(559.822*Math.cos(2*Math.toRadians(pointLat)))+1.175*Math.cos(4*Math.toRadians(pointLat)))/1000;

        angleRange=Math.toRadians(sectorAngle);

        bisectorIVector=maxDistance*Precision.round(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(sectorDirection)),8);
        bisectorJVector=maxDistance*Precision.round(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(sectorDirection)),8);

        IVector=pointLong-centreLong; 
        JVector=pointLat-centreLat;

        if(pointLong<centreLong)
        {
            lower=pointLong;
            upper=centreLong;
        }
        else
        {
            upper=pointLong;
            lower=centreLong;
        }
        count=lower;
        while(Math.ceil(count)<Math.floor(upper))
        {
            jVector=((JVector/IVector)*(count-centreLong))+centreLat;
            longScale+=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(jVector)); 
            count++;
        }
        longScale*=latScale;
        if((upper-lower)>Math.floor((upper-lower)))
        {
            jVector=((JVector/IVector)*(upper-centreLong))+centreLat;
            adjustmentFactor=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(jVector))*latScale*((upper-lower)-Math.floor((upper-lower)));
        }
        longScale+=adjustmentFactor;


        distance=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(longScale,2) + Math.pow(JVector*latScale,2));
        VectorLength=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(IVector,2) + Math.pow(JVector,2));
        if(VectorLength==0.0)
            return true;

        dotProduct=bisectorIVector*IVector+bisectorJVector*JVector;
        EnodeBAngle=Precision.round(Math.acos(dotProduct/(maxDistance*VectorLength)),8);

        if(EnodeBAngle<=Precision.round(angleRange/2,8) && distance<=maxDistance)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Now If the point is within the sector I am trying to mark the point on the sector drawn on map using the google api.

But the problem is that even if my java code return true i.e. point lies within sector still, the corresponding sector plotted on google map shows that the point is outside the sector.

Please help me as to whether did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Distance at the earth surface is not hypotenuse of lat. and long. distances. You have to find length of the great circle arc. Look at the first section [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

JavaScript excerpt:

```
var R = 6371000; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

And you told about sector - but where are sector parameters (starting or central angle, sweep angle)?
Probably you would calculate direction angle (bearing) as shown at the mentioned link in Bearing section.